# Detect Gender of a noun

Tags: python, spacy, cpu-word

I was working with nlp in python spacy. I'm totally beginner on it. I stuck in finding correct pronoun of subject. I managed to return pronoun from subject for I, we, they etc but can't figure out what to do with he/she/it. Because Every Person and Number in grammer has unique pronouns but if subject is 3rd person singular then pronoun will one of he/she/it. If the subject noun is masculine or common, pronoun will be he if it is feminine, pronoun will be she else the pronoun will be it. So how can I figure out what gender the subject is? Is there any way in spacy? If not then can you give me a word list like a dictionary where masculine, feminine and common noun list separated?

### Edit 1:

Some asked for code to understand. So I put it:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

def get_gender(sent:str):
    doc = nlp(sent)
    for token in doc:
        if token.dep_ == "nsubj":
            if token.morph.get("Gender") == ["Masc"]:
                return token.text + "-male"
            elif token.morph.get("Gender") == ["Fem"]:
                return token.text + "-female"
            else:
                return token.text + "-unknown"
    return "unknown"

sent1="He is honest"
sent2="She is honest"
sent3="The man is honest"

print(f"{sent1}: {get_gender(sent1)}")
# Output: He is honest: He-male
print(f"{sent2}: {get_gender(sent2)}")
# Output: She is honest: She-female
print(f"{sent3}: {get_gender(sent3)}")
# Output: The man is honest: man-unknown
```

Here, spacy only detects gender of pronoun but cannot get from noun. Here I used man but it did not return any gender. I want to get gender of a noun which is used to indicate only a separate gender. I want to get the gender of subject. Like: Father - Masculine, Mother - Feminine, Man - Masculine, Table - Neuter, Student - Common, Person - Common

Comment: It's interesting show what you have tried and what errors occurred...

Comment: Please clarify on exactly the task you are trying to do? In particularly the inputs and the outputs you are getting/trying to achieve. e.g. Are you feeding in sentences and let spaCy guess the gender?

Comment: @Ping34 I want to get the gender of subject. I managed to get subject. Now I need to check what gender it is. Like: Father - Masculine, Mother - Feminine, Man - Masculine, Table - Neuter, Student - Common

Comment: If this gets reopened I can actually answer it. But in the meantime you should look into `gensim` and particularly loading the word2vec model form it. This allows you to do something like `model.most_similar_to_given('man', ['male', 'female'])` which outputs "male".

Comment: @Chrispresso The question is closed automatically. I can't do anything. But thanks for your help. I'll learn about gensim.